# PHP image outside web folder

Tags: php, image

I followed solutions pulled right from this site, and it still won't work!

```
<?php
$x='/var/image.jpeg';
if(file_exists($x))
{        
  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($x);

}
?>
```

And nothing outputs...no error, no anything.

The directory is valid. Without the header file, it just displays text similar to the following

```
ÿØÿàJFIF``ÿáXExifMM*1>QQQAdobe ImageR
```

so i presume readfile works.  With the header file, nothing gets displayed, just a blank page.

Any clues? Much help appreciated.

Comment: Is your image RGB or CMYK? Most browsers don't know what to do with CMYK colorspace images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use imagejpeg function instead of readfile
and secondly if you have a file stored with you why would you like to display it with php and not with html img src

Comment: It is outside of the webroot directory.